# Visual Studio Different Line Heights in the Editor

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I've been using vs2013 for quite some time and noticed something that is quite bothering me.

In the Code Editor, lines that contain nothing but symbols *(such as '{', '/' '*' etc..)* have a different **line‑height / font‑size** than other lines that also contain letters.

I search through the settings and couldn't find a way to turn this behavior off.

My question is if there's a way to turn this behavior off, and have consistent line heights throughout my entire code.

Comment: Same found with Visual Studio 2017. The issue is with the extension/add-on `Productivity Power Tools`. The answer provides the accurate solution.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You probably have Productivity Power Tools installed with **Syntactic line compression** enabled. You can turn it off in VS Options - Productivity Power Tools - Other Extensions.

Comment: Fortunately this answer also applies to Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAA!  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, It's funny when installed PPT I thought this was I need, after a while I get annoyed by this and forget how to disable it ^_^

Comment: This also applies to `Visual Studio 2017`.

Comment: This is now located in Options -> Productivity Power Tools -> General -> Syntactic line compression options (uncheck all).

Answer (score 3):

For the VS2019 it is quite similar to the provided solutions:

Tools -> Options-> Productiviry Power Tools -> General

Under "Syntatic line compression options" 
you uncheck:
"Compress lines that does not have any alphanumeric characters" like {,[ and so on

You also can uncheck
"Compress blank lines" but this will be only for lines without anything in it.