# Strange font in Visual Studio 2013 editor

Tags: visual-studio, editor

I'm annoyed by this very strange problem.
I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (Update 4, but I remember the problem being there in previous updates, too), and in the editor, when I start a new line, I see that its height is a little bit smaller than the others.  When I write things that are NOT text or numbers, the row remains small (and with a small font), and at the first keystroke with a letter or number, it becomes equal to the others (growing up a little bit).

[image: Example]

Here you can see a (200% enlarged) example of the problem: you can easily spot the smaller row... at least, until a press a letter.
Right now I even found a 'Use Defaults' in Tools/Options/Environment/Font and Colors, but without any visible result...
Did it happen to anyone else?
Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351636/visual-studio-different-line-heights-in-the-editor

Comment: Wonderful! Yes, that was the case... thanks a lot! :-)