# Line height/font size is variable visual studio 2015 update 3

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-2015

The line height or font height is variable in Visual Studio 2015 and it's driving me nuts. I am using [ProFontWindows](http://tobiasjung.name/profont/) because I like to have more code on my screen without the need to scroll while still being legible.

I do not have this issue in Notepad++, Visual Studio code or other editors.

I can't find anything when I search DDG and Google.

It's very obvious when you look at the line numbers:
[image: Variable heights]

Curly brackets are different size, depending on the line (top `{` is larger than bottom):
[image: Font size different]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351636/visual-studio-different-line-heights-in-the-editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a setting of the Productivity Power Tools. Go to `Options`, `Productivity Power Tools` then `Other Extensions` and disable both checkboxes that relate to `Syntactic line compression options`.

Comment: For anybody having this problem for VS 2017 with Productivity Power Tools, it'll be in Options > Productivity Power Tools -> General -> Uncheck both "Compress blank lines" and "Compress lines that do not have any alphanumeric characters"