# All braces and parenthesis are not of the same size in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I see that with the latest update, the braces `{ }` and `( )` that do not have any text/code next to them are smaller than the braces that have text/code next to them. Consider the screenshot attached:

[image: Screenshot]

See line 7, 9, 12, and 13 where the `{ or }` are much smaller than the braces in lines 10 and 11. I understand that feature helps readability and emphasizes the important code lines than the not so important lines of code. But, is there a way of disabling the feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature of the Productivity Power Tools and can be disabled in the options, see e.g. [Visual Studio Different Line Heights in the Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351636/visual-studio-different-line-heights-in-the-editor?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) or [this post on SuperUser.](https://superuser.com/questions/828695/empty-lines-or-lines-with-symbols-only-have-smaller-font-size-in-vs2013)

Comment: Thank you Felix!